# In JSF is there a way to be notified when a new @ViewScoped object is added?

Tags: jsf, view

I'm working with JSF 2.0 and and existing framework. We have a listener class that allows us to see when objects are being added to the request/session by implementing   HttpSessionAttributeListener and ServletRequestAttributeListener.

Now that we are dealing with @ViewScoped objects I can't figure out a way to get alerted when a ViewScoped object is added. Is there a new listener for this similar to the 2 mentioned above?

Comment: AFAIK ViewScoped beans are also stored in the Session. They should also trigger the HttpSessionAttributeListener.

Comment: It might be that all ViewScoped Beans are just 1 attribute of the Session. In that case I think the only solution might be to implement a PhaseListener and monitor changes in `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewMap()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view scope is represented by [`UIViewRoot#getViewMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIViewRoot.html#getViewMap%28%29). This map only fires the creation and destroy events, the [`PostConstructViewMapEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/PostConstructViewMapEvent.html) and [`PreDestroyViewMapEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/PreDestroyViewMapEvent.html) respectively, which can be listened by a [`ViewMapListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/ViewMapListener.html) implementation (which is by the way quite verbose to set up as compared to e.g. `HttpSessionBindingListener`; the JSF system event listener API is not really well thought out as to configuration). This map does not fire any events for add/remove. To be sure, I even looked in [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.1/javax/faces/component/UIViewRoot.java#UIViewRoot.ViewMap.put%28java.lang.String,java.lang.Object%29) of Mojarra if it didn't sneakily do that, but, unfortunately, it doesn't.

Your best bet is to fire those add/remove events manually in `@PostConstruct` and `@PreDestroy` of your view scoped beans. Noted should be that in JSF 2.0/2.1 the `@PreDestroy` of a view scoped isn't invoked on a session expire. This was an oversight in the spec and is fixed for JSF 2.2.

Comment: I was afraid I would have to solve via the bean. Thanks for confirmation!